# How do i set the color for ics event?

Tags: android, email-attachments, icalendar

From my application i want to send email with ICS event attachment to my customers. I have successfully send mail with .ics file. Now my customers want to display .ics event with some color. Is there any way to add color attribute into .ics file.Please refer my .ics file which was i send

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20131125T062336Z
DTSTART:20131125T143000
DTEND:20131125T150000
SUMMARY:Pro-Lakshman Pro-Single Lesson 30 mins
TZID:Asia/Kolkata
UID:20131125T062337Z-uidGen@Lakshmanan
ORGANIZER;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=Lakshman:mailto:lakshmanan@xxxxxxx-it.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=Karthik:mailto:laksparis@xxxxx.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 4):

No. the [iCalendar format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) does not include any color or styling cues.

Comment: Since Oct. 2016, there's a new RFC with a `COLOR` property: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7986

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You can use the pre-defined Outlook categories to show the schedule in different colors.
Usually Outlook uses category names like "Orange Category", or "Red Category".

So if you add this to your ICS event you can see it in an orange color:

CATEGORIES:Orange Category

Of course, it only works on MS Outlook clients.

Comment: Categories are supported by many clients and many of them also support coloring. But the colors have to be configured separately and don't synchronize. But for the OP question, having a category called "Company events" could be a satisfying solution